# How to clear all the sessions using ProtectedSessionStorage in blazor server app?

Tags: session, blazor, server-application

I am utilizing a Blazor server application in which I have utilized the ProtectedSessionStorage key pair method to store sessions. However, I am facing an issue when it comes to deleting or clearing all the sessions I have stored upon logging out of the application. While there is a way to delete sessions by key, I am seeking a solution to delete all sessions simultaneously.

I have utilized the following code to establish and retrieve sessions, and to date, I have saved a total of 25 sessions. Here is an example of one of the values. However, I am currently attempting to delete these 25 stored values, but I am unsure of how to achieve this.

//set session
ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("Client", null);

//get session
var clientID = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync("Client");

//Delete multiple sessions
???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ProtectedSessionStorage` lacks the `ClearAll()` feature, consider invoking a JavaScript method to clear all keys from either `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` upon user logout as an alternative.

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime 

@code {
    public async ValueTask RemoveAllStorageKeys()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("removeAllStorageKeys");
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    window.removeAllStorageKeys = () => {
        localStorage.clear(); //remove all keys from localStorage 
        //sessionStorage.clear(); //remove all keys from sessionStorage 
    }
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what would be the correct way to give reference to the JS file on the razor component?

Comment: In .NET Core 6+, you can import the required file for isolated JavaScript using the following syntax: `await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Pages/{RazorFileName}.razor.js")`. Alternatively, for the traditional approach, you can include the JavaScript function in a common JavaScript file, such as `Site.js` located in the `wwwroot` folder, and reference this file in either `_host.cshtml` or `_Layout.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** `Clear` method for `ProtectedSessionStorage` [Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.server.protectedbrowserstorage.protectedsessionstorage?view=aspnetcore-7.0), you are going to have to delete each key manually.

For example, storing a collection of keys in memory and updating it everytime you create a key, then when the user logs out loop through each key and delete it.

```cs
HashSet<string> sessionKeys = new(){"Key1","Key2","Client"};
public async Task Logout()
{
    foreach (var key in sessionKeys)
    {
        await ProtectedSessionStore.DeleteAsync(key);
    }
    // Logout user
}
```